# Problem with getting GlobalPosition coordinates of a mouse click

Tags: c#, mouseevent, godot, godot4

I'm trying to get the hang of getting global coordinates on a mouse click. For example, to generate a mob or change the state of some object in the game area.
But when I dug into the InputEventMouseButton, it turned out that this event only receives viewport coordinates... not global ones.
Maybe I didn't fully understand the InputEventMouseButton?
Or does anyone know an alternative way to achieve the goal?

To begin with, what exactly are local and global coordinates for the InputEventMouseButton? Tests have shown that GlobalPosition is always 2 times larger than Position.
But I just can’t understand why this is so...
As a result, this code generates mobs in local coordinates:

```
public override void _UnhandledInput(InputEvent @event)
{
    if (@event is InputEventMouseButton mouseEvent_1 && Input.IsActionPressed("attack"))
    {
        EnemySlime newSlime_1 = Slime.Instantiate<EnemySlime>();
        newSlime_1.Position = mouseEvent_1.Position;

        AddChild(newSlime_1);
    }
}
```

But if the hero (and the camera following him) moves to the side, no matter if I use GlobalPosition, add Camera Position to the mouse click position, or anything else, the mobs don't want to spawn where I click.

P.S., I write in C#, but if you describe the implementation in GDScript, later I will somehow translate it into C#.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my question:

```
    public override void _UnhandledInput(InputEvent @event)
{
    if (@event is InputEventMouseButton mouseEvent_1 && Input.IsActionPressed("attack"))
    {
        EnemySlime newSlime_1 = Slime.Instantiate<EnemySlime>();
        newSlime_1.Position = GetGlobalMousePosition();

        AddChild(newSlime_1);
    }
}
```

GetGlobalMousePosition() gives the necessary coordinates.

Source: https://ask.godotengine.org/11538/get-mouse-position-in-world?show=11538#q11538